# Concatenação de duas listas encadeadas

Tags: c#, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

O problema é:

> Escreva um programa e faça uma função para concatenar duas listas de inteiros em uma terceira lista que deverá ser retornada pela função, em C#.

Minha duvida é somente em como concatenar a lista.

Código da classe que representa a lista (`Lista`)

```
using System;

namespace ListaLib
{
    public class Lista
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Referência do primeiro nó (elemento) da lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista InicioLista { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtora da classe lista
        /// </summary>
        public Lista()
        {
            InicioLista = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove um valor da lista
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="valor">Valor a ser removido</param>
        /// <returns>true se encontrar e false se não encontrar</returns>
        public bool Remove(int valor)
        {
            bool valorRetorno = false;

            NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;

            // Verificar se a lista está vazia
            if (auxiliar != null)
            {
                // Percorrer  lista (navegar) até achar o nó com o valor desejado
                while ((auxiliar != null) && (auxiliar.informacao != valor))
                {
                    // Passa para o próximo elemento da lista
                    auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
                }

                // So atualizar a lista se o valor foi encontrado
                if (auxiliar.informacao == valor)
                {
                    // Verificar se existe um proximo elemento na lista
                    if (auxiliar.proximo != null)
                    {
                        // Remover a referencia do nó anterior
                        (auxiliar.proximo).anterior = null;
                    }

                    // Verificar se é o primeiro da lista
                    if (InicioLista.informacao == valor)
                    {
                        InicioLista = InicioLista.proximo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Verificar se existe um proximo elemento na lista
                        if (auxiliar.proximo != null)
                        {
                            (auxiliar.proximo).anterior = auxiliar.anterior;
                        }

                        // Fazer o anterior do auxiliar apontar para o proximo do auxiliar
                        (auxiliar.anterior).proximo = auxiliar.proximo;
                    }
                }
            }

            return valorRetorno;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adiona um novo valor na lista
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="valor">Valor a ser adicionado</param>

        public void Add(int valor)
        {
            NoLista novoNo = new NoLista();
            novoNo.informacao = valor;

            // Verificar se é o primeiro da lista
            if (InicioLista == null)
            {
                InicioLista = novoNo;
            }
            else
            {
                NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;

                while (auxiliar.proximo != null)
                {
                    auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
                }

                auxiliar.proximo = novoNo;
                novoNo.anterior = auxiliar;
            }
        }


        }

        public void Imprime()
        {
            NoLista auxiliar = InicioLista;
            Console.WriteLine("Imprimindo a lista");

            // Percorrer a lista até o fim
            while (auxiliar != null)
            {
                // Imprimir o valor
                Console.WriteLine(auxiliar.informacao);

                // Navegar para o próximo nó
                 auxiliar = auxiliar.proximo;
            }
        }
    }
```

A classe que representa os nós desta lista (`NoLista`)

```
namespace ListaLib
{
    public class NoLista
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Aramazena a informação
        /// </summary>
        public int informacao { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Referência para o próximo nó (elemento) na lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista proximo { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Referência para o nó (elemento) anterior na lista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista anterior { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtora da classe NoLista
        /// </summary>
        public NoLista()
        {
            informacao = -1;
            proximo = null;
            anterior = null;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: O que seria "Lista"?

Comment: Seu exemplos esta obscuro, você esta tratando seu paramentos como objetos e falar em listas ... poderia explicar melhor ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é uma lista que ele mesmo implementou, bem provavelmente.

Comment: @LINQ isso mesmo amigo, você me entendeu. Porém não to conseguindo concatenar, tem alguma solução for me?

Comment: @user89590 Não sei o que você quer dizer com concatenar, na verdade, eu não entendi nada da sua pergunta. Se você [edit] e deixar o seu problema claro, tenho certeza que eu posso te ajudar, sem isso não consigo.

Comment: @user89590 Agora eu saquei a ideia. Tem como [edit] e colocar a estrutura da sua lista?

Comment: @LINQ Done olha ai

Comment: @user89590 E a classe noLista, por favor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras diferentes.

A primeira é concatenar os nós da segunda lista na primeira, ou seja, modificar a primeira lista e adicionar todos os nós da outra lista. Isso seria mais interessante se fosse um método interno de `Lista`.

O código seria assim:

```
public void Concat(Lista toConcat)
{
    var no = InicioLista;

    while(no.proximo != null){
        no = no.proximo;
    }

    no.proximo = toConcat.InicioLista;
    toConcat.InicioLista.anterior = no;
}
```

A segunda maneira de fazer isso é criando uma terceira lista, esta tendo todos os elementos das duas anteriores. Pra fazer isso não tem muito mistério, você vai precisar passar por todos os elementos das duas listas e adicioná-los numa outra.

O código poderia ser assim:

```
public static Lista Concatenar (Lista l1, Lista l2) 
{
    var novaLista = new Lista();
    Add(novaLista, l1);
    Add(novaLista, l2);
    return novaLista;
}

private static void Add(Lista nova, Lista velha)
{
    NoLista p = velha.InicioLista;      
    nova.Add(p.informacao);   

    while (p.proximo != null) {
        p = p.proximo;          
        nova.Add(p.informacao);
    }
}
```

[Veja as duas versões funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bKIutb)

Comment: Se você não se importar com a estrutura das listas originais, o primeiro método é mais performático.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado E consome menos memória. Embora isso não seja um problema nos dias atuais xD

Comment: achei interessante por essa observação para acaso alguém caia de paraquedas sem maiores conhecimentos e fique pensando "poxa, mas que tolice esse primeiro método se eu posso usar o segundo é continuar com a mesma estrutura". E sobre a memória, mais pura verdade! Primeiro método, memória extra `o(0)` (nem `o(1)` que é constante, mas `o(0)` porque não usa nada mesmo); segundo método, memória extra `o(|a| + |b|)`